# CheckIn,CheckOut project For specific User Using PSI?

Tags: workflow, psi, ms-project-server-2010

i had a business case that i had to checkin,checkout the project by PSI in the work flow but when i
check out the project i cant continue the work flow stages the PWA writes that iam check out the project in another session and i need to continue the work flow from the PWA? any help or suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Do you reset your sessionId? You have to store it during the whole process.
Here is a short example:

```cs
//set guids for session and job
Guid sessionId = Guid.NewGuid();
Guid jobId = Guid.NewGuid();

//checkout in the current session
projectSvc.CheckOutProject(ProjectId, sessionId, "custom field update checkout");

//do something (for example, update a project) with the same sessionId!
bool validateOnly = false;
projectSvc.QueueUpdateProject(jobId, sessionId, project, validateOnly);

//simply wait, if you don't use queuing services
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);

//create a new job ID for the checkin, sessionId stays the same as before!
jobId = Guid.NewGuid();

//checkin the project
bool force = false;
string sessionDescription = "updated custom fields";
projectSvc.QueueCheckInProject(jobId, ProjectId, force, sessionId, sessionDescription);

//wait again (very ugly)
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
```

Check my answer here: [Setting custom fields using the PSI - Microsoft Project Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421313/setting-custom-fields-using-the-psi-microsoft-project-server/9482746#9482746)